# Enter hours only in SQL

Tags: query

Is it possible to enter the hours only for an employee?  For example, I would like to either enter or import the total hours worked for a week, but I keep getting errors.

I will want to calculate hours based on in and out punches in the future, but I want to start with a simple hours and minutes entry.  I have looked but have not been able to get any of the suggestions to work.

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpID, EmpHours)
VALUES (1000, (10:00:00));
```

Thanks!

Comment: hours only, or minutes too?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use a datetime field without the date part.

But you can use a well-know date and add the time part to this date:

> ```
> DECLARE @mydate datetime;
>
> SET @mydate = CAST('1900/01/01 10:02' AS datetime);
> SELECT @mydate;
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name)    |
> | :------------------ |
> | 01/01/1900 10:02:00 |
> ```

Or, you can use a time field to store times

> ```
> DECLARE @mytime time(4);
> SET @mytime = '10:00:00';
> SELECT @mytime;
> ```
>
> ```
> | (No column name) |
> | :--------------- |
> | 10:00:00         |
> ```

Assuming the `EmpHours` column is a time type column, you need to modify your `INSERT` statement like this:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEE(EmpID, EmpHours)
VALUES (1000, ('10:00:00'));
```

Note the single quotes around `'10:00:00'` - those are required around character-based literals.  Note there are no single quotes around the `1000` - that is a numeric value, and does not require single quotes.

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=a6588f8e5dc4e2e57de55ec6cf1304c7)*

Answer (score 2):

If you want to represent *amounts of time* or *durations*, you *do not* want to use columns of type *time*. You actually want to use columns of type *interval*.

Check: [SQL basics: Datetime and interval data types](http://www.techrepublic.com/article/sql-basics-datetime-and-interval-data-types/)

Not many databases implement them, [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html), however, does.

For instance, you could define your table like:

```
CREATE TABLE employee_hours
(
    employee_id integer NOT NULL /* REFERENCES employee(employee_id) */,
    work_duration interval NOT NULL
) ;
```

You would insert values like this:

```
INSERT INTO employee_hours (employee_id, work_duration)
VALUES (1,  '8:15'), 
       (1,  '7:55') ;
```

This way, you can *add* intervals, and get the whole worked hours:

```
SELECT
     employee_id, sum(work_duration) AS total_work_time
FROM
     employee_hours
GROUP BY
     employee_id ;
```

And you get

```
 employee_id | total_work_time
 ----------: | :--------------
           1 | 16:10:00
```

If the database you work with is not able to use *intervals*, I would suggest that you just use an `integer` column, call it `minutes_worked`, and use it just to count minutes (so: `'7:55'` becomes `7*60+55` minutes)

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=1120b018d3243f13706dfaef62949d5e)*